# Shopping cart session problems

Tags: session, coldfusion, shopping-cart

I created a shopping cart using Coldfusion and it's session based.
It seems to be fine for me, but people are having trouble adding items to the Cart.

There is no error, but the cart says empty.

I would imagine that they have cookies and session enabled.

Any basic steps in resolving this??

I have one idea: the Cart redirects to https and I find some browsers have a security issue with the ssl, the thing is that when people contact the company that they can buy they don't mention a security issue.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Are you perhaps using a shared SSL, and you're actually jumping across domains? Make sure that if the user is adding to their cart from www.mydomain.com, that you check them out from https://www.mydomain.com, and not https://mysite.ssl.com. Also check, after adding something to the cart, do they see their cart on the non-secure pages, but not on the secure pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a few things to start to work on as you look in to this:

1. For reasons unexplainable, people like to move back and forth through the ordering process. Do you have a cfparam tag or something that clears out the session cart?
2. Have you wrapped code around the "add to cart" functionality to see what the current state of their session (and cookies) is?
3. What is the timeout on your session variables? When is the session.cart variable initialized?
4. Is there any pattern to which browser(s) are having trouble?

There are many things that can go wrong. Good news is it'll be a lot of diagnosis but the cure is likely quite simple.

Comment: I noticed that it is Internet Explorer v 7.  where do  istart with that??

Comment: Next step is to make it happen for yourself. See if you can re-create the cart clearing. Does it happen on the http-https transition or at some other time?  Be sure to try on another machine too.

Comment: what was the real problem? did you ever figure it out?